# pod install fails with error: error:1006706B:elliptic curve routines

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, rubygems, cocoapods

I have two Macs both up to date with OS X and Xcode.  On one, I can install cocoapods and the pods specified in my project's podfile.  The other fails:

> pod install --verbose   Preparing
>
> Updating local specs repositories
>
> Creating shallow clone of spec repo `master` from
>   `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git`   $ /opt/local/bin/git clone
>   https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master --depth=1   Cloning into
>   'master'...   error: error:1006706B:elliptic curve
>   routines:ec_GFp_simple_oct2point:point is not on curve while accessing
>   https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
>   fatal: HTTP request failed [!] Unable to add a source with url
>   `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master`. You can try
>   adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.
>
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:48:in
>   `rescue in find_or_create_source_with_url'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:53:in`
>   find_or_create_source_with_url'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:616:in `block in sources'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:615:in`map'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:615:in `sources'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:211:in`update_repositories'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:129:in
>   `block in resolve_dependencies'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:59:in`
>   section'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:128:in
>   `resolve_dependencies'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:104:in`
>   install!'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/command/project.rb:71:in
>   `run_install_with_update'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/command/project.rb:101:in`
>   run'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.9.1/lib/claide/command.rb:312:in
>   `run'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:48:in`
>   run' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/bin/pod:44:in
>   `<top (required)>' /usr/bin/pod:23:in`load' /usr/bin/pod:23:in
>   `'

I've completely uninstalled and reinstalled cocoapods and tried everything else remotely relevant on SO.  To me it smells like an encryption/decryption issue or https/ssl issue.

On the machine having trouble, I did have a pre-beta Xcode installed, but I've since deleted it and made sure it's command line tools are set correctly.

Anyone have suggestion on how to remedy this or diagnosis it further?

Answer (score 0):

I resorted to taking drastic action.  I uninstalled Xcode (app, libraries, preferences), uninstalled cocoapods, and uninstalled MacPorts (I could have had an old port getting in the mix).  Reinstalled Xcode and cocoapods and now it works.